# Creating circle inside pie chart in android. How to center it into the middle?

Tags: android

I am using [this tutorial](http://androidvenkatkrishna.blogspot.co.at/2011/08/adding-piechart-to-view.html) for creating a pie chart in android.

code:

```
public void Draw(Context context, Canvas canvas) {          
            if (mState != IS_READY_TO_DRAW) {
                return;
            }
            canvas.DrawColor(mBgcolor);
            mBagpaints.AntiAlias = true;
            mBagpaints.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
            mBagpaints.Color = context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.black);
            mBagpaints.StrokeWidth = 0.0f;
            mLinePaints.AntiAlias = true;
            mLinePaints.Color = context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.black);
            mLinePaints.StrokeWidth = 2.0f;
            mLinePaints.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            RectF mOvals = new RectF(mGapleft, mGapTop, mWidth - mGapright, mHeight - mGapBottm);
            mStart = START_INC;
            PieDetailsItem item;
            for (int i = 0; i < mdataArray.Count(); i++) {
                item = (PieDetailsItem) mdataArray.ElementAt(i);
                mBagpaints.Color = item.color;
                mSweep = (float) 360* ((float) item.count / (float) mMaxConnection);
                canvas.DrawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, mBagpaints);
                canvas.DrawArc(mOvals, mStart, mSweep, true, mLinePaints);
                mStart = mStart + mSweep;
            }
            mState = IS_DRAW;
        }
```

I would like to add a black circle inside a pie chart but I have no idea how. Can someone give me an hint or idea?

edit: black circle I mean pie inside a pie where is number 16.

[image]

I have tried this but not working. It is not in the middle. How to center it to the middle?

```
Bitmap localBitmap3 = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Paint localPaint2 = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        localPaint2.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        localPaint2.AntiAlias = true;
        localPaint2.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
        //localPaint2.TextSize = "text";
        localPaint2.Color = context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white);
        localPaint2.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));
        //canvas.DrawBitmap(localBitmap3, 0.0F, 0.0F, localPaint2);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(localBitmap3, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
        canvas.DrawCircle(5F, 5F, 30F, localPaint2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add a black circle inside" exactly? Also, it would be nice if you could post your relevant code here; that site is a mess.

Comment: I have edited my code. With black circle I mean pie inside a pie.

Comment: Thank you for posting the code, but I still don't understand what you need. Could you make a simple diagram?

Comment: I paste an image. Check a circle inside a pie where you can see number 16

Comment: You could subsequently draw a 360 deg solid black circle with the drawarc function. and then also use the drawText to draw the '16'

Comment: Thank you. I have pasted my code but i snot in the middle. Can you give me mabye a hint or example how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializations for `blackPaint`, `whitePaint`, and the text:

```
Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
Paint whitePaint = new Paint();
whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
whitePaint.setTextSize(40); // Adjust this as needed

String text = "16";
```

You would add this after your for loop:

```
canvas.drawCircle(mOvals.centerX(), mOvals.centerY(), mOvals.width() / 4, blackPaint);
float textWidth = whitePaint.measureText(text);
canvas.drawText(text, mOvals.centerX() - textWidth / 2, mOvals.centerY() + whitePaint.getTextSize() / 2, whitePaint);
```

Comment: Please note, this example also assumes that the pie chart is circular; i.e., its width and height are equal. If this is not the case, let me know and I'll update the answer. However, I've not seen an oval-shaped pie chart, and it would, in fact, defeat the purpose of a pie chart.